# how to generate signed apk in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

In my case, I have my signature key and I have generated the apk with function menu`build--->generate signed Bundle/Apk`

Here are the steps how I generate this apk:

step 1:

[image]

step 2:

[image]

finally:

[image]

When I put this generated release apk into my real device, it will work well.

But when I tried to send this apk to my application center, it said that I don't have any signature file in this apk.

According to many issues found on google, I have noticed that there was actually no signature file in my apk at all. It seems that Android studio's `build--->generate signed Bundle/Apk` didn't work at all, there was only a release with no signature that generated.

I'm quite new in android developing. I wonder if there are some mistakes in my gradle settings.

My application has 2 `gradle.build` file like this picture:
[image]

the `gradle.build` out side the app directory is :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the `gradle.build` file inside app directory is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('D:\\CodeRepository\\app-key-store\\SimpleSender.jks')
            storePassword '123123123'
            keyAlias 'simple-sender-key'
            keyPassword '123123123'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.simplesender"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.9.2'
    implementation group: 'com.alibaba', name: 'fastjson', version: '1.2.78'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '31.0.1-android'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'

}
```

I don't know why I can't generate an apk with signature...

Comment: `my application center` - do you mean you are using play store or some other mdm to deploy or share your application

Comment: @Nitish yes, I'm using a third part app store just like play store to deploy my application, but I found that others who succeesfully deployed their apks will all have a signature file with ```.RSA``` suffix in the apk's META-INF, but I don't have one.

Comment: You code and the way you signed are fine, if you are trying to send this via some mdm platform then read their guidelines. They might have their on signing logic on top of this apk.

Comment: @william can you tell us which third party store you are referring to?

Comment: So I'm quite confused. I'm a very new beginner of android for less than a week. I don't know if the problem is occurred in ```gradle.build```. I have done nothing but adding dependencies into ```gradle.build```

Comment: @william no nothing wrong with your gradle file

Comment: An public app store of our trade supplier named Sunmi, in their docs, I have to submit an apk contains signature file, but I don't have anything looks like signature file...

Comment: @RajSuvariya But I have found some issues showing that a successful signed apk will contains files ending with ```.RSA```which I don't have that at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238600/discussion-between-raj-suvariya-and-william).

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for `@Raj Suvariya` and `@Nitish`

The problem was solved according to their kindness instructions. And how I solved this problem is showing below:

First of all I'm using AS of version

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
```

If you are using the same AS, you won't find any options to select signing version when you trying to generate a signed apk with your signing key like this picture showing below (they all have these 2 options).

[image]

after finishing building, the APK can be run in my device an works just all right, but I cannot deploy it to app store because app store told me that I have no signature file in META-INF.

The solution is to `Explicitly specify` the signing strategy like this in `build.gradle` and here is the code. the important code is

```
            v1SigningEnabled true
            v2SigningEnabled true
```

here is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('D:\\CodeRepository\\app-key-store\\SimpleSender.jks')
            storePassword 'xxx'
            keyAlias 'simple-sender-key'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            v1SigningEnabled true
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('D:\\CodeRepository\\app-key-store\\SimpleSender.jks')
            storePassword 'xxx'
            keyAlias 'simple-sender-key'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            v1SigningEnabled true
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }

.....your other configs.....

}
```

Try run generate signed apk again, and problem solved, and deployment to app store succeed.